# Azure Data Factory -> Tumbling Window

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a **schedule trigger** that executes a pipeline **every day once at 6:15 AM**. And now my requirement is I have multiple pipelines which I want to run post-completion of my pipeline part of the said **schedule trigger**. How can I achieve this using the **Tumbling window?** I don't find a way.

Thanks,
Vivek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a dependency on the scheduling trigger in the Advanced section of the tumbling window trigger settings.

[image]

Comment: Hi, The trigger that I add to the dependencies will run only once a day. So I need the tumbling trigger as well to run only once. In this case, as per your screenshot, recurrence is set to 15 minutes?

Comment: @VivekKB You can just set the recurrence to 24 hours. Updated the screenshot to reflect that.